# Crashing while adding two UINavigationControllers to tab bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a view, which is having two sub views, while adding those two subviews in tab bar it crashes in main. Following is the code..

```
        block_list = [[ofi_vc_blocked_list alloc] init];
        ab_blk_navig_controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:block_list];
        ab_navig_controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ab_window];
        ab_tab_bar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; // ab_tab_bar is tab bar controller
        ab_tab_bar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:ab_navig_controller, ab_blk_navig_controller, nil];
```

While doing that, it crashes with following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<ofi_vc_address_book: 0x6868710> should have parent view controller:<ofi_vc_main_page_controller: 0x6c4b830> but actual parent is:<UITabBarController: 0x6869830>'
```

Any idea guys?

Comment: Where does ab_window come from? Where is it made? It sounds like ab_window is already in the view hierarchy and you're trying to force it into a different spot resulting in the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given an example , add the following statement for the first and the for the second tabBar2 .

```
UITabBarItem *tabBar1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" image:[UIImage      imageNamed:@""] tag:0];
navigation1.tabBarItem = tabBar1;

 UITabBarItem *tabBar2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" image:[UIImage      imageNamed:@""] tag:1];
navigation2.tabBarItem = tabBar2;

tabBarCon.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigation1,navigation2, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarCon;
```